# Scrapy strange output but works with curl

Tags: scrapy

I am running below scrapy command

```
scrapy shell "https://www.vr.de/service/filialen-a-z/a.html'
```

In return I am getting data like below,

[image]

This data do not have any information.

If I use curl to get the data it is accurate with all information.

Can someone please advise me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

user  headers in scrapy shell

```
>>> url = 'https://www.vr.de/service/filialen-a-z/a.html'
>>> headers={"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 5_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/534.46 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.1 Mobile/9B179 Safari/7534.48.3"}
>>> r=scrapy.Request(url, headers=headers)
>>> fetch(r)
2021-05-08 16:12:27 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.vr.de/service/filialen-a-z/a.html> (referer: None)
>>> for data in response.css('div.module.module-teaser.ym-clearfix'):
...     print(data.css('a::attr("href")').get())
...     print(data.css('div.text::text').get())
```